# Run FM Script Via XML URL from Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, filemaker

I'm developing a custom JS web map that is supposed to execute a FileMaker script on our server depending on where the user clicks on the map. The script is called from the web using a XML URL in a syntax specific to FileMaker. No data needs to be returned when the script is executed.

I have successfully written JS that executes when the user clicks on the map. I also know that the XML URL is correct, because when I enter it in my browser, the script fires on our server.

However, when I try to get the click event to send the XML request, nothing happens. I am new to XML, so I think it has something to do with how I am calling the XML URL. My web map is on the same server as the FileMaker.

Here is the JS that I have so far. Right now I am just trying to get it to execute a test script. Eventually, I will be passing the variable SegId into the FileMaker script:

```
// Watch for pop-up event
view.popup.watch("selectedFeature", function(event) {
    // if pop-up returns a feature... (to avoid error if user clicks too far from segment)
    if (event && event.attributes && event.attributes.CIRCUIT_ID) {
    // set segId equal to value of CIRCUIT_ID
     var segId = event.attributes.CIRCUIT_ID;
    // render a style change to the selected feature (functiondefined below)
    featureLayer.renderer = generateRenderer(segId);

function sendSegId() {
    console.log("XML request sent");        
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://Admin@206.123.249.187/fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=WebViewerTest&-lay=Maps&-script=test&-script.param=88&-findall", true);
    xhttp.send();
    console.log("XML request executed" + segId);    
}
    sendSegId();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all script steps are Server compatible for the FileMaker script you are running and make sure Admin user has privilege to execute scripts.

Comment: I know the script is server compatible and the Admin user has the privilege to execute scripts because it runs when I enter the XML URL into a browser's URL window. The issue is that the the XML URL is not being triggered by the function sendSegId - so something is wrong with the XMLHttpRequest, but I don't know what.

Comment: I am trying the same script in the browser and it gives me an error 200 - no record access or error 4.

Comment: Yes - it is giving me the same error now as well. This was not happening when I left on vacation last week. Our IT guy is insisting no changes were made to the FM server, so I am at a loss as to what is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

try

http://206.123.249.187/fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=WebViewerTest&-lay=Maps&-script=test

this returns error 4 indicating that there is one of the steps which is not web compatible.

Remove all script steps from the test script and leave only one, e.g. commit record and then run the script.

Another issue could be if you have an incompatible script step in the script which is being triggered when you open the database.